# Repeat X times a searching color

Tags: lua

l need to search this color only 10 seconds. if is false it must continue to next step.

> local color repeat
> color = getColor(674,660)
> usleep(1000000)
> -- Wait a while until( color == 12778257)
> -- Continue to do what's next

What can l do ?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. You are waiting for some pixel to turn into some color? You want to wait 10 seconds but: you want to check once, wait 10s, check again? Or you need to check frequently during 10s? Which frequency?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained your question well.  This `getColor()` function isn't native to Lua;  it's specific to whatever app you're using, so how are we supposed to know the output?

I feel like that 10-second timer isn't needed, and you just need to learn how to mix `Red Green Blue` values instead.

https://www.mathsisfun.com/hexadecimal-decimal-colors.html

```
local found = false
secs = os .clock() +10

while os .clock() < secs and not found do
    if getColor( 674,660 ) == 12778257 then found = true end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.
l have implemented this and work perfect. But if anyone need l let it here

```
loops = 0
```

local color
repeat
loops = loops + 1
color = getColor(1231,680)
usleep(1000000)
-- Wait a while
until( color == 12843795 or loops == 15)
-- Continue to do what's next

or :

```
startTime = os.time()
```

local color
repeat
color = getColor(1231,680)
usleep(1000000)
-- Wait a while
until( color == 12843795 or os.difftime(os.time(), startTime) > 15)
-- Continue to do what's next